# how to make call just based on date with awk bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, command-line

I need help with a bash awk command.

I want this output :

```
Aug 05 08:54:52 Installed: perl-XML-Simple-2.14-4.fc6.noarch
Aug 05 08:57:10 Installed: yum-utils-1.1.16-21.el5.centos.noarch
Aug 05 14:59:19 Installed: libgcc-4.1.2-55.el5.i386
Aug 05 14:59:19 Installed: libstdc++-4.1.2-55.el5.i386
```

I tried : `cat /var/log/yum.log | awk '{ print $1, $2, $3 } print 'Aug 05''`
but it isn't working. Can someone help me with with a correct command based on the date?

Thanks.

Comment: Kindly do mention the expected output in code tags in your post.

Comment: Few people will know the contents of `yum.log`, so you should include the corresponding lines of that input file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do the following on systems with yum/rpm :

```
#!/bin/bash

file=/tmp/file.dat
rpm -qa --qf '%{INSTALLTIME} (%{INSTALLTIME:date}): %{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}.%{ARCH}\n' | sort -n > $file

# Date Ranges
start="Apr 28 07:50:01 2015"
finish="Feb 10 10:00:10 2017"

# Print items between range
while IFS= read -r line ;do
        curr=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $1}')
        if [ $curr -ge $(date -d "${start}" +"%s") ] && [ $curr -le $(date -d "${finish}" +"%s") ] ;then
                echo $line
        fi
done < "${file}"
[[ -f $file ]] && rm -f "${file}"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `awk '/Aug 05/' /var/log/yum.log` or `grep "Aug 05" /var/log/yum.log` (edited as suggested).  It looks like you want the entire line of the log file whenever it is on august fifth.  Awk will default to printing any line that matches the pattern.

You don't have to cat the file into awk, by the way as you can see in my example.  Awk can take a file name as an argument and work on it.  The pattern typically (always?) follows the command block.  The pattern is delimited by `/` and can contain typical regex.

Comment: $1,$2 and $3 is not enough (as output has 5 columns). `awk '/Aug 05/{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5}' /var/log/yum.log` . I agree that OP is not clear on the format of input file but my guess is `awk '/Aug 05/' /var/log/yum.log` or `grep 'Aug 05'  /var/log/yum.log` is what he needs.

Comment: @CorentinLimier edited as suggested

Comment: And being picky I would add `^` to the regexp : `/^Aug 05/` . But sometimes you would prefer avoiding this to catch badly formatted lines as well.

Comment: thanks this fix my problems : awk '/Aug 05/ { print $0 }' /var/log/yum.log

Comment: If this solved your issue, would you please accept it as the correct answer?  Thank You

Answer (score 1):

The right syntax for this is actually :

```
awk '/Aug 05/ { print $0 }'  /var/log/yum.log
```

Im printing **$0** because in your example the fields you are mentioning would only print the date.

Regards!

Comment: thanks this fix my problems : awk '/Aug 05/ { print $0 }'  /var/log/yum.log